# Is this a bug in Haskell's printf "%g"?

Tags: haskell, printf

This c++ program

```
#include <cstdio>
int main(void)
{
  double x = 1.0;
  printf("%g\n", x);

  double y = 1.25;
  printf("%g\n", y);
}
```

seems to perform correctly according to my [understanding](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Format_Specifiers_in_C/C++) of fprint "%g", as it produces the following output:

```
1
1.25
```

However, the output from this Haskell program

```
import Numeric     (showGFloat)
import Text.Printf (printf)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let x = 1.0 :: Double
  putStrLn $ printf "%g" x
  putStrLn $ showGFloat Nothing x ""

  let y = 1.25 :: Double
  putStrLn $ printf "%g" y
  putStrLn $ showGFloat Nothing y ""
```

is

```
1.0
1.0
1.25
1.25
```

My question is: Why does Haskell print "1.0" instead of "1", as I expected it to? The [Haskell docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Text-Printf.html) for printf suggest that the Haskell behavior should be the same the C++ behavior.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: I see "C printf like formatter" and "g  general format float" but nothing more specific, so it's hard to tell whether this is intended behavior or not.

Comment: It's intended to be compatible, so it looks like a bug.

Comment: I suppose I should have asked if this is a GHC bug instead of a Haskell bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It really looks like a bug....

In the C spec, it is very clear that %g is to cut off trailing '.000...'s.  See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf, p. 313:

> Finally, unless the # ﬂag is used, any trailing zeros are removed from the
>   fractional portion of the result and the decimal-point character is removed if
>   there is no fractional portion remaining.

The bug exists in Hugs also, I tried it.

Also, awk uses printf, and there is a Linux command line version of printf, and both are compatible with the c version, so ghci and hugs are certainly the odd man out.

This isn't the only incompatibility, as printf should (according to the spec) truncate at 5 digits when no precision is given, and it doesn't.

In Haskell

```
> printf "%g\n" 1.111111111111111111111
```

yields

```
1.1111111111111112
```

while, in C

```
int main() {
  printf("%g\n", 1.111111111111111);
}
```

yields

```
1.11111
```

The Haskell report doesn't ever mention the Text.Printf library, so despite it being in base, I don't think you can consider this either a Haskell, ghc, or hugs bug, but just a library bug.

Comment: jamshidh - Thanks for your detailed response.  I guess I'll file a bug. Not sure with whom yet, but I'll look.